# Inheritance with a subclass private variable

Tags: java

[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akwpo.png)

I have been struggling with my Java project since the parent class has no "answer" variable and the subclass has the private "answer" variable. Even though there is a getAnswer method in the parent class, there is no answer variable in the parent class of the UML diagram. Any suggestions is highly appreciated

Here is the java file that connects both the parent and its subclasses. The only thing in the subclasses are constructors  while the parent class has a constructor and 2 getters only.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */


public class SimpleQuiz {
    private ArrayList<Question> myQuestions;
    private int currentQuestion;
    
    public SimpleQuiz()
    {
        myQuestions =new ArrayList<Question>();
        
        myQuestions.add(new ShortAnswerQuestion("1. What is the color of apple?","Red"));
        myQuestions.add(new ShortAnswerQuestion("2. What is my favorite food?","Bacon"));
        myQuestions.add(new FillinBlankQuestion("3. I only have to _____ my head above water one more week","keep"));
        myQuestions.add(new FillinBlankQuestion("4. eight times _____ is equal to fourty","five"));
         myQuestions.add(new TrueFalseQuestion("5. Every animal has a tail","False"));
         myQuestions.add(new TrueFalseQuestion("6. A baby has more bones than an average adult","True"));
        
        myQuestions = shuffleList (myQuestions);
        currentQuestion=0;
    }
       
          public String getCurrentQuestion()
        {
            return myQuestions.get(currentQuestion).getQuestion();
        }
        
        
        public String getCurrentAnswer()
        {
            return myQuestions.get(currentQuestion).getAnswer();
        }
        
        
        public boolean checkCurrentAnswer(String answer)
        {
           return myQuestions.get(currentQuestion).checkAnswer(answer);
        }
        
        //Returns true if this quiz has another question
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return currentQuestion < myQuestions.size() - 1;
        }
        
        public void next() throws Exception 
        {
            if(currentQuestion == myQuestions.size()-1)
            {
                throw new Exception("There are no more questions.");
            }
            currentQuestion++;
        }
        
        //Shuffle the list
private ArrayList<Question> shuffleList (ArrayList<Question> inputList)
        {
                ArrayList<Question> randomList = new ArrayList<Question>();
                
                Random r=new Random();
                int randomIndex=0;
                while(inputList.size() > 0)
                {
                   randomIndex=r.nextInt(inputList.size());  //Choose a random object in the list
                   randomList.add(inputList.get(randomIndex));   //add it to the new, random list
                   inputList.remove(randomIndex);   //remove to avoid duplicates
                }
                
                return randomList;  //return the new random list
        }
}
```

Comment: It would be useful more details and your code, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to write a Quiz Application where the are questions and answers are hardcoded. Then when you test the application, it will randomly pick a question and the user will answer it. I have already made progress in the code but, I am stuck since I have little idea on how can I use the String answer variable on the subclasses to the parent class

Comment: Even if the UML notation does not show it, is it possible, that Question is an abstract class? and the `getAnswer` methods have to be implemented in the subclasses?

Comment: @csalmhof it is only stated that it is a standard class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where you have got the UML diagram, but it can be optimized. Looking at the problem statement, the Question should not be a class, it should be an interface if not an abstract class, and should not have any instance variables and constructors. Having an instance variable 'question' in superclass makes no sense. The Question superclass should act as a marker, below is the code

```
interface Question{

String getQuestion();

String getAnswer();

boolean checkAnswer(String str);
}
```

Now the implementing class needs to provide a definition of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear to me, you got UML and need to implement in code the exact definition ?

if yes I think there are 3 options only:

1. Missing field `answer` in parent
2. Parent is abstract, and `getAnswer()` is an abstract method
3. In Parent implement method `getAnswer()` as empty, and override it in the children and return the private answer of child